# Execute Immediate 'Query' ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 56 bytes (callheap,qerrmbv[]: qerrmObnd)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to run a script in sqlplus that fill a table called 'ccb_check' through an "execute immediate" but I get 'ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 56 bytes (callheap,qerrmbv[]: qerrmObnd)'

```
set serveroutput on
declare

begin

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO  ccb_check
SELECT
/*+DRIVING_SITE(A)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(B)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(C)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(D)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(E)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(F)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(G)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(H)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(I)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(J)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(K)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(L)*/
/*+DRIVING_SITE(M)*/
DISTINCT
          C.ADHOC_CHAR_VAL AS BANCO,
          M.HOMERE_ID,
          D.CHAR_VAL AS TITRE_RUBRIQUE,
          A.CHAR_VAL AS STITRE_RUBRIQUE,
          E.CHAR_VAL AS BENEFICIAIRE,
          F.TOS_ID AS ID_TOS,
          B.DESCR AS DESCR_TOS,
          B.SA_ID AS ID_EDC_MODELE,
          F.SA_ID AS ID_EDC_CLIENT,
          G.ACCT_ID AS ID_COMPTE_CLIENT,
          G.START_DT AS DT_DEB_EDC_CLIENT,
          G.END_DT AS DT_FIN_EDC_CLIENT,
          I.DESCR_TMPLT AS LIBELLE_FACTURE,
          I.RS_CD,
          K.MIG_ID_COMPTE_CLIENT,
          CASE
             WHEN J.RS_CD IN (SELECT RS_CD
                                FROM CI_RC@LDE_CIBLE
                               WHERE BF_CD LIKE ''%ABO%'')
             THEN
                ''DIAMETRE COMPTEUR''
             WHEN J.RS_CD IN (SELECT RS_CD
                                FROM CI_RC@LDE_CIBLE
                               WHERE BF_CD LIKE ''%TR%'')
             THEN
                ''TRANCHE''
             ELSE
                ''UNIQUE''
          END
             AS TYPE_TARIF,
          (SELECT DESCR
             FROM CI_LOOKUP@LDE_CIBLE
            WHERE     FIELD_VALUE = G.SA_STATUS_FLG
                  AND UPPER (field_name) LIKE ''%SA_STATUS_FLG%''
                  AND TRIM (language_cd) = ''FRA'')
             Etat_EDC, sysdate DD
     FROM CI_TOS@LDE_CIBLE B,
          CI_UA_CHAR@LDE_CIBLE C,
                   CI_TOS_SA@LDE_CIBLE F
                LEFT JOIN
                   CI_TOS_CHAR@LDE_CIBLE A
                ON F.TOS_ID = A.TOS_ID AND A.CHAR_TYPE_CD = ''STITRE-R''
             LEFT JOIN
                CI_TOS_CHAR@LDE_CIBLE D
             ON F.TOS_ID = D.TOS_ID AND D.CHAR_TYPE_CD = ''TITRE-R''
          LEFT JOIN
             CI_TOS_CHAR@LDE_CIBLE E
          ON F.TOS_ID = E.TOS_ID AND E.CHAR_TYPE_CD = ''BENF-TYP'',
          CI_SA@LDE_CIBLE G,
          CI_SA_RS_HIST@LDE_CIBLE H,
          CI_RV_L@LDE_CIBLE I,
          CI_RC@LDE_CIBLE J,
          RN_ACCT@LDE_CIBLE K,
          CI_TOS_CHAR@LDE_CIBLE L,
          CM_RUBRIQUE_TOS@LDE_CIBLE M
    WHERE     F.TOS_ID = B.TOS_ID
          AND B.UA_ID = C.UA_ID
          AND F.SA_ID = G.SA_ID
          AND F.SA_ID = H.SA_ID
          AND H.RS_CD = I.RS_CD
          AND I.RS_CD = J.RS_CD
          AND F.TOS_ID = L.TOS_ID
          AND TRIM (F.TOS_ID) = TRIM (M.TOS_ID)
          AND G.ACCT_ID = K.CCB_ID_COMPTE_CLIENT
          AND I.LANGUAGE_CD = ''FRA''
          AND L.CHAR_TYPE_CD = ''NAT-SERV''
          AND L.CHAR_VAL != ''FRAIS''
          AND C.CHAR_TYPE_CD = ''BANCO''
';
EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN
ROLLBACK; --to Savepoint restore_ccb;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('restore insert INS_CCB, SQLCODE : ' ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
end;
/

select * from v$pgastat;

aggregate PGA target parameter  373293056   bytes
aggregate PGA auto target   240648192   bytes
global memory bound 74657792    bytes
total PGA inuse 122972160   bytes
total PGA allocated 185925632   bytes
maximum PGA allocated   1368005632  bytes
total freeable PGA memory   20512768    bytes
process count   68  
max processes count 299 
PGA memory freed back to OS 2705889689600   bytes
total PGA used for auto workareas   22077440    bytes
maximum PGA used for auto workareas 517334016   bytes
total PGA used for manual workareas 0   bytes
maximum PGA used for manual workareas   1628160 bytes
over allocation count   2418    
bytes processed 4274855246848   bytes
extra bytes read/written    498305049600    bytes
cache hit percentage    89,56   percent
recompute count (total) 2473622
```

I need your help In fact the query works when I remove 'execute immediate' so i want to know is there any way to run the script with "execute immediate" statement.

This query actualy returns over 1 million rows.

Comment: How many rows does this query return?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to allocate more memory to the Oracle instance. This question would therefore be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see all your tables are remote. I think the more efficient (basing on last tuning experiences in similar situation) will be to create view on remote db and query only necessary columns. That approach will reduce amount of sent data.